# Button with Image, Image Disappear when clicking the button iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, button

```
@IBAction func btnPrimaryAction(_ sender: Any) {
        btnPrimary.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_on.png") , for: UIControlState.normal)
        btnSecondary.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_off.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        btnNewAdd.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_off.png") , for: UIControlState.normal)
        payType = 1
    }
```

I'm using this code to change the button image when clicking the button. But button image disappear when clicking the button in iOS 10.

Please Help me with this 
Thanks is advance

Comment: are you sure the state of the button is .normal ? as I can see you're setting the image only for a state .normal, therefore if the state is anything else your image will be empty

Comment: State is always normal im not changing the state ... its working on one view controller same code everything no change but not working on other view controller

Answer (score 0):

I think this is efficient way to use `UIButton` State. `UIButton` have multiple state like `UIControlState.normal,UIControlState.selected,UIControlState.highlighted` etc..
You can solve your problem easily by using UIButton's  `UIControlState`.
First you need to set Image to your button like this way.
In `viewDidLoad` method.

```
// if you have add the "checkbox_off.png and checkbox_on.png" in Images.xcassets then get the image you need to write as below
//UIImage(named : "checkbox_off") no need to add extention like ".png"

btnPrimary.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_off.png") , for: UIControlState.normal)
btnSecondary.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_off.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
btnNewAdd.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_off.png") , for: UIControlState.normal)

// Selected    
btnPrimary.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_on.png") , for: UIControlState.selected)
btnSecondary.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_on.png"), for: UIControlState.selected)
btnNewAdd.setImage(UIImage(named : "checkbox_on.png") , for: UIControlState.selected)
```

Now in your function just change the button state

```
@IBAction func btnPrimaryAction(_ sender: Any) {
    btnPrimary.selected = true
    btnSecondary.selected = false
    btnNewAdd.selected = false
    payType = 1
}
```

Comment: i tried this but didnt work for me . idk whats happening .. same code works in one controller and doesnot work in other controller